# Power app formula error

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have an error on this calculation:

Trying this:

```
Text(Value(TextInput2)+Value(TextInput2_1)/2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error message? Where are you adding this formula, which control and property?

Comment: Hi @Jose1978, did you try using solution given below? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change the "Format" property of the Text Input controls to "Format.Number".

Then try using below formula on "Text" property of label control:

```
Text((Value(TextInput2.Text)+Value(TextInput2_1.Text))/2)
```

OR

```
Text((TextInput2.Text + TextInput2_1.Text) / 2)
```